# Is there more than one way to tag a fellow user in comments?

Tags: support, comments

Recently on the question: [What is the biblical basis for the Athanasian Creed's statement that believing in the Trinity is necessary for salvation?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/49022/what-is-the-biblical-basis-for-the-idea-that-believing-in-the-trinity-is-necessa)

I noticed two users using initials like IOW and TLDR
Instead of the @ ...... In the beginning of comments.

What do the initials represent?
Is there a new way to alert other users that your comment is directed at them?

Answer (score 5):

They're not tags, they mean In Other Words, and Too Long Didn't Read (used to introduce a summary.)

These abbreviations are easy to look up on the internet you know :)

Comment: ROFL. I feel stupid

Comment: @Kris NW ;) haha

Comment: Yeah, exactly, IKR ;-P